# Compiling MySQL 5.7.20 in CentOS 7 Issues (A Lot)

Tags: mysql, centos

I am trying to setup a MySQL server using CentOS (No GUI) and I need to switch to OpenSSL instead of YaSSL in order to have access to the encryption tools.

The issues happen when runing the cmake.  At first I got the error that cmake was not able to find boost, I fixed this adding the parameter -DWITH_BOOST.

The cmake line is as follows.

```
cmake . -DWITH_READLINE=ON -DWITH_SSL=system -DWITH_BOOST=/usr/local/src/mysql-5.7.20/boost/
```

After the adjustment I ran again the CMAKE the I got several errors.

1. SSL Error, cmake can not find the OpenSSL files.  I checked if the library was installed, I also downloaded the tar.gz file and decompress it and pointed the cmake to the folder, none of this worked.
2. Can not find NUMA libraries, again I checked and it is installed, at this point I ran the system update to check for everything but this did not solve the issue.
3. Can not find the ncurses, the same thing, is on the system but for some reason cmake is not able to find those.
4. Can not fin libaio, I didn't have this one installed, I installed, ran cmake again, and again cmake was not able to find it.

I been looking around, trying to figure out all this issues, I've been joining information from different websites but still not able to figure out this.

Thanks ahead to everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try `make clean; cmake clean; ldconfig` then run your cmake command. Sometimes the system can't find the shared libraries, and `ldconfig` refreshes the library search path. This helped once when I was compiling something (emscripten?) which required a lot of libraries which I was installing as compilation errors arose.

The `make clean; cmake clean` will ensure that the compiler isn't looking at the old library search path when you recompile.

Answer (score 4):

You're facing the dependencies hell with MySQL. If you don't really need to compile from the sources, you still can install with the RPM which is much easier. The RPM method is described here : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-yum-repo-quick-guide/en/

As you're asking a ready-to-go install from the sources, this is what I just did and it worked, on a fresh CentOS 7.4 minimal, 2 vcpus 3Gb :

```
yum group install -y 'Development Tools'
yum install -y cmake ncurses-devel curl

curl -Ovk https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-5.7/mysql-5.7.20.tar.gz
tar zxf mysql-5.7.20.tar.gz
cd mysql-5.7.20

cmake . -DDOWNLOAD_BOOST=1 -DWITH_BOOST=$HOME/boost -DENABLE_DOWNLOADS=1
make -j2
make install
```

After that you need to configure it, add the startup scripts, and of course secure it. Here are some additional docs :
http://howtolamp.com/lamp/mysql/5.6/installing/
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-secure-installation.html

Comment: I really need in order to use OpenSSL, my other option will be to buy the commercial version of mysql but it is too expensive.

Comment: There is no documentation about which dependencies are required, but ncurses and bison. Remember that for compiling you need the "-devel" packages of each too such as ncurses-devel . I installed from the sources some times but I didn't track which dependencies I needed to add, I just remember there are many and this will take around 20 compilations with failures until you've finished.

Comment: Yes I saw the ncurses-delevel but I was not able to install that one, always got errors and yum install ncurses-delevel does not do the trick.  I guess I'll have to switch to another Distro like ubuntu that has more support for autoinstall packages

Comment: I have installed MySQL and ncurses-devel (not "delevel" be careful) around 20 times, and always got it to run perfectly. ncurses is in the base repo, can't have any problem to install theoritically.

Comment: Umm I am pretty sure I screwed it up with the ncruse by missreading and misstyping.  I haven't been able to test your recommendation, been stuck with a network deployment but later today I am going to do it.  I'll let you know if atleast I can solve the ncurse issue.